# How can we prove that each point (hkl) in the reciprocal lattice corresponds to a set of lattice planes (hkl) in the real space lattice?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

In crystallography, we always speak about the direct and reciprocal lattice spaces. One property about these spaces in mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_lattice), as follows:

> Each point (hkl) in the reciprocal lattice corresponds to a set of lattice planes (hkl) in the real space lattice.

Can anyone give a proof for this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reciprocal lattice is spanned by a set of basis vectors with the property:
$$ \vec K_i \cdot \vec R_j = \frac{2\pi}{V} \delta_{ij}, $$
where $V$ is the volume of the unit cell.
Planes perpendicular to some vector $\vec k$ can be given by equations of the form (for now, with arbitrary $d \in \mathbb R$ which is $\left|\vec k\right|$-times the plane's distance from the origin):
$$ \vec k \cdot \vec r = d. $$
If we now take a (non-zero) vector $\vec k = (hkl) = h \vec K_1 + k \vec K_2 + l \vec K_3$ from the inverse lattice and multiply it by a vector $\vec r = [mno] = m \vec R_1 + n \vec R_2 + o \vec R_3$ from the direct lattice, we get:
$$\vec k \cdot \vec r = \frac{2\pi}{V} (hm + kn + lo). \tag{$*$} $$
That is, for each $\vec k$ from the reciprocal lattice, all points from the direct lattice will be on a family of parallel planes (that are all perpendicular to $\vec k$).

We can always choose $h, k, l$ to be coprime (otherwise the same set of planes is described, as we can factor the greatest common divisor on the left-hand and right-hand side of $(*)$). Furthermore, the right-hand side of $(*)$ can produce any integer (times $2\pi/V$) because the greatest common divisor can always be represented as an integer linear combination (the integers doing so can be found by the extended Euclidean algorithm, see also [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)). So the family of planes is equally spaced with distance $D = \frac{2\pi}{V \left| \vec k \right|}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Sebastian. Can you give a reference to your answer, please?!

Comment: No, I just re-derived it while writing this and I don't think I ever read it in a book (I've only seen the proof in lectures).